# Learning resources for usb device and device driver devolopment

Tags: usb, device-driver, pic, avr, usb-drive

I have never done any USB development, I'm experienced with programming PIC, AVR micro-controllers and C programming on windows (not windows programming). I want to learn how to develop embedded devices and device drivers that can communicate with PC, Not via serial port emulator in USB hardware.
I like to have some points and resources on who should I approach it.
What software and hardware should I have to start leaning that?

Answer (score 0):

Read this fantastic book: [USB Complete](http://www.lvr.com/usbc.htm) by Jan Axelson.  Also in his site are comprehensive informations too.